# Get "keypress"+"Characters type" pressed / Like this 65:'A'

Tags: javascript

I have a script that it have a full list key-code keypress+Characters each type/ Like this 65:'A'

```
         $(document).on("keypress",function(e){
        var e2 = e || window.event;
        var code = e2.keyCode || e2.which;    console.log(e);
  $('body').text(code+"-"+String.fromCharCode(code)+(chars.hasOwnProperty(code)?chars[code]:"<br>?</br>"));       
    });

var chars = {8:'BackSpace',9:'Tab',12:'Num',13:'Enter',16:'Shift',17:'Ctrl',18:'Alt',19:'Pause',20:'Caps',27:'Esc',32:'Space',33:'!',34:'"',35:'#',36:'$',37:'%',38:'&',39:'\'',40:'(',41:')',42:'*',43:'+',44:',',45:'-',46:'.',47:'/',48:'0',49:'1',50:'2',51:'3',52:'4',53:'5',54:'6',55:'7',56:'8',57:'9',58:':',59:';',60:'<',61:'=',62:'>',63:'?',64:'@',65:'A',66:'B',67:'C',68:'D',69:'E',70:'F',71:'G',72:'H',73:'I',74:'J',75:'K',76:'L',77:'M',78:'N',79:'O',80:'P',81:'Q',82:'R',83:'S',84:'T',85:'U',86:'V',87:'W',88:'X',89:'Y',90:'Z',91:'[',92:'\\',93:']',94:'^',95:'_',96:'`',97:'a',98:'b',99:'c',100:'d',101:'e',102:'f',103:'g',104:'h',105:'i',106:'j',107:'k',108:'l',109:'m',110:'n',111:'o',112:'p',113:'q',114:'r',115:'s',116:'t',117:'u',118:'v',119:'w',120:'x',121:'y',122:'z',123:'{',124:'|',125:'}',126:'~',127:' ',128:'',129:'',130:'',131:'',132:'',133:'',134:'',135:'',136:'',137:'',138:'',139:'',140:'',141:'',142:'',143:'',144:'',145:'',146:'',147:'',148:'',149:'',150:'',151:'',152:'',153:'',154:'',155:'',156:'',157:'',158:'',159:'',160:' ',161:'¡',162:'¢',163:'£',164:'¤',165:'¥',166:'¦',167:'§',168:'¨',169:'©',170:'ª',171:'«',172:'¬',173:'­',174:'®',175:'¯',176:'°',177:'±',178:'²',179:'³',180:'´',181:'µ',182:'¶',183:'·',184:'¸',185:'¹',186:'º',187:'»',188:'¼',189:'½',190:'¾',191:'¿',192:'À',193:'Á',194:'Â',195:'Ã',196:'Ä',197:'Å',198:'Æ',199:'Ç',200:'È',201:'É',202:'Ê',203:'Ë',204:'Ì',205:'Í',206:'Î',207:'Ï',208:'Ð',209:'Ñ',210:'Ò',211:'Ó',212:'Ô',213:'Õ',214:'Ö',215:'×',216:'Ø',217:'Ù',218:'Ú',219:'Û',220:'Ü',221:'Ý',222:'Þ',223:'ß',224:'à',225:'á',226:'â',227:'ã',228:'ä',229:'å',230:'æ',231:'ç',232:'è',233:'é',234:'ê',235:'ë',236:'ì',237:'í',238:'î',239:'ï',240:'ð',241:'ñ',242:'ò',243:'ó',244:'ô',245:'õ',246:'ö',247:'÷',248:'ø',249:'ù',250:'ú',251:'û',252:'ü',253:'ý',254:'þ',255:'ÿ',256:'Ā',257:'ā',258:'Ă',259:'ă',260:'Ą',261:'ą',262:'Ć',263:'ć',264:'Ĉ',265:'ĉ',266:'Ċ',267:'ċ',268:'Č',269:'č',270:'Ď',271:'ď',272:'Đ',273:'đ',274:'Ē',275:'ē',276:'Ĕ',277:'ĕ',278:'Ė',279:'ė',280:'Ę',281:'ę',282:'Ě',283:'ě',284:'Ĝ',285:'ĝ',286:'Ğ',287:'ğ',288:'Ġ',289:'ġ',290:'Ģ',291:'ģ',292:'Ĥ',293:'ĥ',294:'Ħ',295:'ħ',296:'Ĩ',297:'ĩ',298:'Ī',299:'ī',300:'Ĭ',301:'ĭ',302:'Į',303:'į',304:'İ',305:'ı',306:'Ĳ',307:'ĳ',308:'Ĵ',309:'ĵ',310:'Ķ',311:'ķ',312:'ĸ',313:'Ĺ',314:'ĺ',315:'Ļ',316:'ļ',317:'Ľ',318:'ľ',319:'Ŀ',320:'ŀ',321:'Ł',322:'ł',323:'Ń',324:'ń',325:'Ņ',326:'ņ',327:'Ň',328:'ň',329:'ŉ',330:'Ŋ',331:'ŋ',332:'Ō',333:'ō',334:'Ŏ',335:'ŏ',336:'Ő',337:'ő',338:'Œ',339:'œ',340:'Ŕ',341:'ŕ',342:'Ŗ',343:'ŗ',344:'Ř',345:'ř',346:'Ś',347:'ś',348:'Ŝ',349:'ŝ',350:'Ş',351:'ş',352:'Š',353:'š',354:'Ţ',355:'ţ',356:'Ť',357:'ť',358:'Ŧ',359:'ŧ',360:'Ũ',361:'ũ',362:'Ū',363:'ū',364:'Ŭ',365:'ŭ',366:'Ů',367:'ů',368:'Ű',369:'ű',370:'Ų',371:'ų',372:'Ŵ',373:'ŵ',374:'Ŷ',375:'ŷ',376:'Ÿ',377:'Ź',378:'ź',379:'Ż',380:'ż',381:'Ž',382:'ž',383:'ſ',384:'ƀ',385:'Ɓ',386:'Ƃ',387:'ƃ',388:'Ƅ',389:'ƅ',390:'Ɔ',391:'Ƈ',392:'ƈ',393:'Ɖ',394:'Ɗ',395:'Ƌ',396:'ƌ',397:'ƍ',398:'Ǝ',399:'Ə',400:'Ɛ',401:'Ƒ',402:'ƒ',403:'Ɠ',404:'Ɣ',405:'ƕ',406:'Ɩ',407:'Ɨ',408:'Ƙ',409:'ƙ',410:'ƚ',411:'ƛ',412:'Ɯ',413:'Ɲ',414:'ƞ',415:'Ɵ',416:'Ơ',417:'ơ',418:'Ƣ',419:'ƣ',420:'Ƥ',421:'ƥ',422:'Ʀ',423:'Ƨ',424:'ƨ',425:'Ʃ',426:'ƪ',427:'ƫ',428:'Ƭ',429:'ƭ',430:'Ʈ',431:'Ư',432:'ư',433:'Ʊ',434:'Ʋ',435:'Ƴ',436:'ƴ',437:'Ƶ',438:'ƶ',439:'Ʒ',440:'Ƹ',441:'ƹ',442:'ƺ',443:'ƻ',444:'Ƽ',445:'ƽ',446:'ƾ',447:'ƿ',448:'ǀ',449:'ǁ',450:'ǂ',451:'ǃ',452:'Ǆ',453:'ǅ',454:'ǆ',455:'Ǉ',456:'ǈ',457:'ǉ',458:'Ǌ',459:'ǋ',460:'ǌ',461:'Ǎ',462:'ǎ',463:'Ǐ',464:'ǐ',465:'Ǒ',466:'ǒ',467:'Ǔ',468:'ǔ',469:'Ǖ',470:'ǖ',471:'Ǘ',472:'ǘ',473:'Ǚ',474:'ǚ',475:'Ǜ',476:'ǜ',477:'ǝ',478:'Ǟ',479:'ǟ',480:'Ǡ',481:'ǡ',482:'Ǣ',483:'ǣ',484:'Ǥ',485:'ǥ',486:'Ǧ',487:'ǧ',488:'Ǩ',489:'ǩ',490:'Ǫ',491:'ǫ',492:'Ǭ',493:'ǭ',494:'Ǯ',495:'ǯ',496:'ǰ',497:'Ǳ',498:'ǲ',499:'ǳ',500:'Ǵ',501:'ǵ',502:'Ƕ',503:'Ƿ',504:'Ǹ',505:'ǹ',506:'Ǻ',507:'ǻ',508:'Ǽ',509:'ǽ',510:'Ǿ',511:'ǿ',711:'ˇ',728:'˘',729:'˙',731:'˛',733:'˝',913:'Α',914:'Β',915:'Γ',916:'Δ',917:'Ε',918:'Ζ',919:'Η',920:'Θ',921:'Ι',922:'Κ',923:'Λ',924:'Μ',925:'Ν',926:'Ξ',927:'Ο',928:'Π',929:'Ρ',931:'Σ',932:'Τ',933:'Υ',934:'Φ',935:'Χ',936:'Ψ',937:'Ω',945:'α',946:'β',947:'γ',948:'δ',949:'ε',950:'ζ',951:'η',952:'θ',953:'ι',954:'κ',955:'λ',956:'μ',957:'ν',958:'ξ',959:'ο',960:'π',961:'ρ',962:'ς',963:'σ',964:'τ',965:'υ',966:'φ',967:'χ',968:'ψ',969:'ω',977:'ϑ',978:'ϒ',982:'ϖ',8211:'–',8212:'—',8216:'‘',8217:'’',8218:'‚',8220:'“',8221:'”',8222:'„',8224:'†',8225:'‡',8226:'•',8230:'…',8240:'‰',8242:'′',8249:'‹',8250:'›',8254:'‾',8260:'⁄',8364:'€',8465:'ℑ',8472:'℘',8476:'ℜ',8482:'™',8501:'ℵ',8592:'←',8593:'↑',8594:'→',8595:'↓',8596:'↔',8629:'↵',8656:'⇐',8657:'⇑',8658:'⇒',8659:'⇓',8660:'⇔',8704:'∀',8706:'∂',8707:'∃',8709:'∅',8711:'∇',8712:'∈',8713:'∉',8715:'∋',8719:'∏',8721:'∑',8722:'−',8727:'∗',8730:'√',8733:'∝',8734:'∞',8736:'∠',8743:'∧',8744:'∨',8745:'∩',8746:'∪',8747:'∫',8756:'∴',8764:'∼',8773:'≅',8776:'≈',8800:'≠',8801:'≡',8804:'≤',8805:'≥',8834:'⊂',8835:'⊃',8836:'⊄',8838:'⊆',8839:'⊇',8853:'⊕',8855:'⊗',8869:'⊥',8901:'⋅',8968:'⌈',8969:'⌉',8970:'⌊',8971:'⌋',9001:'〈',9002:'〉',9674:'◊',9824:'♠',9827:'♣',9829:'♥',9830:'♦'};
```

Now :
I need to add to script that it could to be auto-detect after press key or press Item clicked with mouse

After press key or press Item clicked with mouse like in virtual-keyboard this website [enter link description here](http://allanguages.info/#layouts=) get "keypress"+"Characters type" pressed

Like this {Item clicked or key pressed is = 65:'A'}

Comment: Is the full code-to-character array really necessary to put on SO?

Comment: Instead spurious objection please help me, It is for searcher input keys

Comment: I still can't figure out what the question is. could you add a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/eruwoh/4/edit  ,  I need capture Item clicked or pressed with mouse on virtual-keyboard.js